# New Trisquel installation always at 100% CPU, log files grow very fast, graphical glitches, etc

Tags: linux, cpu, logging, keymap, trisquel

About a week ago, I installed Trisquel on a rather old (2010-ish) computer, and ever since then there has been an issue which I had never found a solution for, but hesitated from asking for support for until now. The problem was that the CPU use was constantly near 100% all the time. [I took a look at the processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQtoQ.png)  yet I have no idea what most of this means or what to do because this is my first Linux install.

Another issue I had noticed was that the log files were growing incredibly fast. Even when I was gone from the computer they were growing and I have to clear them out every time I log in because they take up all the hard disk space of the root partition (which is 20gb).

Today I also experienced [strange graphical glitches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah7eZ.png) and unless I am the only one who sees them in that, the screencap shows actual moving glitches. Coupled with this, my keyboard also completely changed its mapping, so I cannot type certain characters despite being set to the keymapping I want it to use, and this coincidentally also happened to my other computer as well except the keymapping became almost completely random.